# microsoft graph API using filter on get sharepoint items

Tags: odata, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

i am trying to filter my Sharepoint Items results query with the Microsoft Graph API as explained [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters#filter) so i am trying this
`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items`
so i tried adding

`?&filter=od eq 1`, or copying from `expand` `?filter=fields(select%3Did) = 1`, none works. please help

Comment: There is a feature request open here, please vote:
https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/aa3cdd9a-b9f3-ec11-a81b-000d3a00c008

Answer (score 15, accepted):

FOUND IT!

`&filter=fields/id eq 1`

`&filter=fields/ContentType eq 'Apartment Page'` -> NO DOUBLE QUOTES

`&filter=startswith(fields/id,1)`

Comment: Unfortunatly this doesn't seem to work anymore (testing in Graph Explorer)

Comment: This worked for me with setting header as Prefer : HonorNonIndexedQueriesWarningMayFailRandomly

Answer (score 3):

@mhbuur

add request header
Prefer: HonorNonIndexedQueriesWarningMayFailRandomly

Comment: Thanks. This is not really a production ready solution though as it "MayFailRandomly" and it will certainly fail with large lists.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to filter by id just do:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items/{id}
```

Comment: The id field is just for the example. The real challenge was an angular app with custom user input on text fields.